# Showing black screen when coming to foreground in ios

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, background-foreground

I am working on an app having facebook integration.
App is working fine for first few times.
if i open the app from background  after 2-3 hrs its showing black screen when it comes to foreground.
I am giving permission for offline access.
Any help would be thankful...

Comment: Havent you added any splash screen to your project at start up ?

Comment: No i dont hav any splash screen...

Answer (score 1):

put a picture named "Default.png" in your project's resource folder may help you.

Comment: Actually i shouldnt be having any splash screen for my app.this problem is happening only if am putting the app idle for 3-4 hrs ,and then launching it...